# Blank getShippingAddress OR getShippingDescription in transactional emails?

Tags: email-templates, transactional

I'm having some trouble with getting two variables to appear in outgoing new order emails.

Essentially, Magento will only populate *one* of either:

> {{var order.getShippingAddress{}.format('html')}}
>
> {{var order.getShippingDescription()}}

And never the two together in the same email.

I've tried splitting them out into separate parts of the email (thinking maybe the html format of addresses was breaking its container) but still to no avail, even if I remove the {{depend}} clause and put the variables inline together.

I'm on 1.9.01 and using Mandrill for transactional emails; avoiding config.xml and using the System -> Transactional Emails section to input custom HTML. The section of the table is here:

http://pastebin.com/Vwe8ANE7

Any ideas, or guidance in troubleshooting? Mandrill and Magento logs aren't really helping - they simply generate a blank span or td where the information should be!

Comment: is `getShippingAddress{}` correct with {} should it not be ()?

Comment: It, apparently, is not! According to the KB it is: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/defining-transactional-variables - turns out that's a typo on the page. Thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 1):

To anyone looking at this; if you've pasted your variables in from the Magento KB ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/defining-transactional-variables ) it's actually incorrect. It should be:

> {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}

Rather than

> {{var order.getShippingAddress{}.format('html')}}

(Thanks to @David)